# Iterating over entire columns and storing the result into a list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I would like to know how I could iterate through each columns of a dataframe to perform some calculations and store the result in an another dataframe.

```
df_empty = []
m = daily.ix[:,-1] #Columns= stocks & Rows= daily returns 
stocks = daily.ix[:,:-1]
for col in range (len(stocks.columns)):
    s = daily.ix[:,col]
    covmat = np.cov(s,m)
    beta = covmat[0,1]/covmat[1,1]
    return (beta)
    print(beta)
```

In the above example, I first want to calculate a covariance matrix between "s" (the columns representing stocks daily returns and for which I want to iterate through one by one) and "m" (the market daily return which is my reference column/the last column of my dataframe). Then I want to calculate the beta for each covariance pair stock/market.

I'm not sure why return(beta) give me a single numerical result for one stock while print(beta) print the beta for all stocks.
I'd like to find a way to create a dataframe with all these betas.

```
beta_df = df_empty.append(beta)
```

I have tried the above code but it returns 'none' as if it could not append the outcome.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: `return` does break the loop, why do you use it like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `return` statement within your for-loop ends the loop itself the first time the return is encountered. Moreover, you are not saving the `beta` value anywhere because the for-loop itself does not return a value in python (it only has side effects).

Apart from that, you may choose a more pandas-like approach using `apply` on the data frame which basically iterates over the columns of the data frame and passes each column to a supplied function as the first parameter while returning the result of the function call. Here is a minimal working example with some dummy data:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as pd

# create some dummy data
daily = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=(100, 5)))

# define reference column
cov_column = daily.iloc[:, -1]

# setup computation function
def compute(column):
    covmat = np.cov(column, cov_column)
    return covmat[0,1]/covmat[1,1]

# use apply to iterate over columns
result = daily.iloc[:, :-1].apply(compute)

# show output
print(result)

0   -0.125382
1    0.024777
2    0.011324
3   -0.017622
dtype: float64
```